# Getting a name error when calling a class

Tags: python, class, naming

```py
class Restaurant:
    """details restaurant atrrubutes"""
    
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        """initialize name and cuisine"""
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        """provide extra details about restaurant"""
        print(f"{self.restaurant_name.title()} is 11 years old and quite expensive to dine at.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        """ reveals restaurants openess"""
        print(f"{self.restaurant_name.title()} is open.")

    my_restaurant = Restaurant("Mike's", "Southern BBQ") # python tells me Restaurant isn't defined here*****
    print(f"My restaurant is called {my_restaurant.restaurant_name}.")
    print(f"It serves {my_restaurant.cuisine_type}.")

    my_restaurant.describe_restaurant()
    my_restaurant.open_restaurant()
```

**edit: resolved, my dumbass forgot to remove the line 17 indent**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\micha\Desktop\python_work\chapter_nine\resteraunt.py", line 1, in 
class Restaurant:
File "C:\Users\micha\Desktop\python_work\chapter_nine\resteraunt.py", line 17, in Restaurant
my_restaurant = Restaurant("Mike's", "Southern BBQ")
NameError: name 'Restaurant' is not defined
**how do I resolve this? I'm quite the novice**

Comment: What'S the error? (The exact trace, with the full error message and traceback)

Comment: It looks like your indentation is off. Should the `my_restaurant = Restaurant(...` line be indented like that?

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is not right. here you go:

```py
class Restaurant:
    """details restaurant atrrubutes"""
    
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        """initialize name and cuisine"""
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        """provide extra details about restaurant"""
        print(f"{self.restaurant_name.title()} is 11 years old and quite expensive to dine at.")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        """ reveals restaurants openess"""
        print(f"{self.restaurant_name.title()} is open.")

my_restaurant = Restaurant("Mike's", "Southern BBQ")
print(f"My restaurant is called {my_restaurant.restaurant_name}.")
print(f"It serves {my_restaurant.cuisine_type}.")

my_restaurant.describe_restaurant()
my_restaurant.open_restaurant()
```

Comment: you're right ;((( thank you